# vpython vector vs numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, vector, vpython

For simple vector algebra, are there any significant differences between VPython's vectors (`visual.vector`) and NumPy's arrays (`numpy.ndarray`)?

I'm making a gas simulator and don't know which is more Pythonic.

Comment: What does  `pythonic`  mean, in this context?

Comment: From The Zen of Python: "There should be one— and preferably only one —obvious way to do it. Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch."

Comment: That notion might be nice within the tightly controlled world of pure Python development, but you are asking about the use of 3rd party packages, developed by different groups and for different uses (though `vpython` does use `numpy`).